# Design Pattern suits for this if else condition?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, pattern-matching

I have three services A, B and C. Every service process input and gives 3 type of output i.e Invalid(I), Valid(V) and Unknown(U).
We have to check if input is valid, invalid or unknown. if any service returns Valid or Invalid we can return that output but if service returns unknown we have to check with other service. Similarly we have to do with every service available A, B, C. If any service gives invalid or valid we can return that and we don't have to check with other service.

Which Design pattern suits for this case?

```
output validate(input, country) {
    response;
    if A support this country {
        response = A(input);
        if response == Invalid or response == Valid {
            return response;
        }
    }
    if B support this country {
        if ((response is null) or (response is unknown)){
            response = B(input);
        }
        if response == Invalid or response == Valid {
            return response;
        }
    }
    if C support this country {
        if ((response is null) or (response is unknown)){
            response = C(input);
        }
        if response == Invalid or response == Valid {
            return response;
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Looks like [chain-of-responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) to me. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this with a `Service` interface.

```
interface Service {
    Collection<Object> supportedCountries();
    Optional<Response> processInput(Object input);
}
```

Have a array of your services

```
List<Service> services = {A,B,C};

for(Service service : services) {
   if(service.supportedCountries().contains(country)) {
     Optional<Response> oResponse = service.processInput(input);
     if(oResponse.isPresent()){
       return oResponse.get();
     }
   }
}
return Response.INVALID; // or null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a strategy pattern to see if applies given a certain condition, and then execute what has to be done if it applies

You can see a very detail example [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy)